# Translation of "get stuck in traffic"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate

> In this city it is normal that one gets stuck in traffic for hours.

I have problem with "get stuck in traffic":

> In dieser Stadt ist es normal, dass man stundenlang im Traffic bleibt.

Is there a better, more direct way to translate?

Comment: Actually, you just forgot to translate "stuck" ;)

Comment: Und "Traffic", außer man meint einen Zigaretten/Zeitungskiosk in Österreich. Wird aber wohl abweichend geschrieben?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrasing is actually closer than you expected.

> In dieser Stadt ist es normal, dass man im Verkehr stecken bleibt.

Another very common way to say it is this:

> ..., dass man stundenlang im Stau steht.

But there are other versions too.